# How to check for the turnout of the last elections and copy it to a specific (later) year (panel data)

Tags: r, panel

I am working with a dataset which includes among others the variables and values presented below. How can I "copy" the latest election turnout (stored in electoral1) before 2004 into the year 2004 for each country. For some countries the last elections date back 2 years, for others 3, 4, 5... I am rather new to R but it seems to me I would need some kind of loop which runs within each Nation. I am grateful for any hint. Many thanks, roland

```
Year    Nation  electoral1 (=turnout)
1994    Albania 
1995    Albania 
1996    Albania 
1997    Albania 730 
1998    Albania 
1999    Albania 
2000    Albania 
2001    Albania 600 => this should go to 2004
2002    Albania 
2003    Albania 
2004    Albania 
2005    Albania 
2006    Albania 
1994    Algeria 
1995    Algeria 
1996    Algeria 
1997    Algeria 656
1998    Algeria 
1999    Algeria 
2000    Algeria 
2001    Algeria 
2002    Algeria 462 => this should go to 2004
2003    Algeria 
2004    Algeria 
2005    Algeria 
2006    Algeria
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the missing data is represented by an `NA`

First, get your dataframe:

```
df = myDataFrame
```

Then, write a function that gets the latest electoral data for a particular country

```
getLatestElecdata = function(Nation,df){
NationIndexes = which(df$Nation == Nation)
elec_by_year = data.frame(Year = df$Year[NationIndexes],electoral1= df$electoral1[NationIndexes])
elec_by_year = elec_by_year[ order(-elec_by_year[,1]), ]
getLatestElec = elec_by_year[which(!is.na(elec_by_year[,2]))[1],2]
return(getLatestElec)
}
```

Now, for each 2004 entry, get the latest data

```
2004indexes = which(df[,1]==2004)

for(i in 2004indexes){
df[i,3] <- getLatestElecdata(df[i,2],df)
}
```

This should solve your problem.